# QtDesigner - missing function under windows 7?

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt-designer, qt-signals

I am using QtDesigner for my Python programming at the moment. Under signals and slots right at the bottom you can add a new signal. I want to add for example a point in the menubar. "Quit" and it should close the mainwindow, if it's activated.

It looks like

actionQuit   --Signal--    MainWindow     close()

Under Ubuntu 12.04 I can choose activated() as a signal. Under the windows version there is no `activated()` under `<Signals>`?

Did I do something wrong or is this just specific to the windows version?

Comment: try using "triggered()" as the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you got the idea of `activated` from, but people are supposed to use the triggered signal for this from QAction:

> [void QAction::triggered(bool checked = false) [signal]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered)
>
> This signal is emitted when an action is activated by the user; for example, when the user clicks a menu option, toolbar button, or presses an action's shortcut key combination, or when trigger() was called. Notably, it is not emitted when setChecked() or toggle() is called.
>
> If the action is checkable, checked is true if the action is checked, or false if the action is unchecked.

Since you have not provided more information whether you use PySide or PyQt, I will give you the canonical Qt one-liner for this which you can easily migrate to your beloved python Qt wrapper:

```
connect(quitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
```